# Homography in Emgu CV 3.0

Tags: emgucv, projection, homography

I am newbie in image processing. I want to do homography my image that I get from capturing camera. Can anyone help me to do homography to my capture image ? Thank so much

This is what I've done and It doesn't work. I'm stuck

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> RGB_Image = CaptureKamera1.QueryFrame();
Image<Bgr, Byte> destImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(352, 288);

imageBox1.Image = RGB_Image;

double[,] srcp = { { 74, 82 }, { 281, 81 }, { 281, 211 }, { 68, 205 } };
double[,] dstp = { { 81, 7 }, { 160, 7 }, { 36, 158 }, { 207, 158 } };
double[,] homog = new double[3, 3];

Matrix<double> srcpm = new Matrix<double>(RGB_Image);
Matrix<double> dstpm = new Matrix<double>(destImage);
Matrix<double> homogm = new Matrix<double>(homog);

CvInvoke.cvGetAffineTransform(srcpm.Ptr, dstpm.Ptr, homogm.Ptr);
CvInvoke.cvPerspectiveTransform(RGB_Image.Ptr, destImage.Ptr, homogm.Ptr);

imageBox2.Image = destImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/bacdc955-287f-017c-16d7-39dda4e357c3.htm) method. He has two constructors so choose what will be better for you.